# Installation tinymce in zend application

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, tinymce

I'm a noob to jquery. I try to install the plugin tinymce on my Zend application.

In the header of my page I put:

```
<?php
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.9.1.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/tinymce.min.js');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea#content-post'
    });
 </script>
```

(As indicated on model official website tinymce)

But in my firebug console I have:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

   <!DOCTYPE html>                                      tinymce.min.js (ligne 8)

   TypeError: l is not a constructor                    tinymce.min.js (ligne 8)
```

Do you know why I have this error please?

Comment: Can you try and view the tinymce.min.js file in a browser and see if that works?

Comment: I found the solution.

In my book I just put js file tinymce.min.js then need to use all repertory tinymce